# List last 10 public-activities of a facebook user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As far as you know, normally, Facebook lists friend's activities in a sidebar when you are in your home-page in Facebook.

**Q1 :** I want to know if is there any way to list **other people** public activities? (people whom are not our friend).

Does the `Graph` api has any method to do this? if so how I can use it?

**Q2 :** And as another question, can I list activities of one of my **friends** using `Graph`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answers:

1) No. There is no such endpoint.

2) No. Friends permissions have been deprecated since Graph API v2.0.

Comment: Do you mean, I must be his/her friend to be able to list his/her public activities?

Comment: This means that you cannot access the friend's info anymore, because it's technically no longer possible via the Graph API since v2.0